# how to stop VS2010 from automatically including files for Ansi C project

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, ansi-c

I am refactoring a legacy and i need to lean on the compiler for a bit.
Some settnig in Visual Studio is not working like i want it to work.

file a.c

```
int main (int i, char** l)
{
    dostuff(i);
}
```

file b.h

```
//empty header
```

file b.c

```
void dostuff(int i);


void dostuff(int i)
{
    //bla
}
```

`a.c` does not include the `b.h` nor does `b.h` meantion dostuff. Since dostuff is not static the symbol is exported. If i delete `b.c` the compiling fails.

I would like to set up vs2010 so that it generates an error for `a.c` because the symbol `dostuff` was not imported via include.

What setting would do that for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code should be generating a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3ct4kz9.aspx) (at level 3) so you should be able to see that something is wrong after compilation from that. If you want an error:

You can add `#pragma warning (error : 4013)` in your `a.c` file.

Alternatively add `/we4013` to the additional options under `Configuration properties->C/C++->Command Line`

This treats the warning generated by your code as an error

Comment: The ammount of warnings in that code is staggering. They are all noise and i have to deal with them one by one... the '/we4013' option is exactly what i need.